# Resizing Targeted Window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to resize the targeted window after my hyper link is clicked is this possible?

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="myID"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../names /view.aspx?myID={0}"                     
DataTextField="name"                      
        HeaderText="Name"                      
        SortExpression="Name"                      
        ItemStyle-Width="100px"                      
        ItemStyle-Wrap="true"                      
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"                      
        Target="_blank" />
```

Comment: what does your rendered HTML look like?

Comment: The Html is huge what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this attribute

```
onclick="window.open(this.href,'','width=640,height=480');return false;"
```

to your `<asp:HyperLinkField />`